# How to get the Google doc drawings through Document api or appscript

Tags: image, rest, document, google-docs-api

Hi I have a Google Document that has a Drawing inserted in it, Now I want to get the link of the drawing or get the blob out of the drawing and show

As I use the Document API I was not able to get its properties as is was just empty objects

can someone let me know whether it is feasible or not , If feasible can someone let me know how to fetch the info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

It's currently not possible no handle drawings programmatically.

#### Feature requests:

There's a somewhat related feature request in Issue Tracker:

- [Add ability to create and modify drawings](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36754517)

This is reported in the context of [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), though, and since the FR is quite old, I'd suggest you to file a new one for Docs API, using [this template](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=555502&template=1211190).